# How to enable login option while configuring NuGet feed in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, nuget

I want to enable the login option for nuget feeding in visual studio.

**My Requirement:**

I want to feed nuget in visual studio. When user feed this, I want to enable login option.

The login popup contains email and password. After user login, the API returns to application. The API contains email  and password. I want to validate the email and password in controller. If validate success means, we want to allow the user to use the package.

How to achieve this? Is there anyone have idea related to this?

[URL Feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlX6e.png)

Let me know if any concerns occurs.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the Login authentication feature to your application?

Comment: I want to add login authentication when configuring nuget feed in visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

> How to enable login option while configuring NuGet feed in visual studio?

At this moment, There is no such login popup window to complete the login authentication. Visual Studio save the credentials in the `nuget.config` file.

If you head to the folder:

```
C:\Users\­<UserName>\­AppData\­Roaming\­NuGet
```

you can add the following to the `NuGet.config` file:

```
<packageSourceCredentials>
    <Contoso>
        <add key="Username" value="user@contoso.com" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="33f!!lloppa" />
    </Contoso>
    <Test_x0020_Source>
        <add key="Username" value="user" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="hal+9ooo_da!sY" />
    </Test_x0020_Source>
</packageSourceCredentials>
```

You can also secure this by adding the credentials via NuGet.exe:

```
Nuget.exe Sources Add -Name Contoso -UserName user@contoso.com -Password 33f!!lloppa
```

If you want have a login popup window to complete the login authentication, you can use a third party hosting service such as [Rider 2018.1 EAP](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/03/06/credential-providers-private-nuget-feeds-rider-2018-1-eap/).

Hope this helps.